# Unable to set customized icon from the assert folder to p-menuitem-icon in microfrontend?

Tags: typescript, sass, micro-frontend, single-spa-angular

I am trying to set a customized icon from css to p-menuitem icon but it is unable to fetch it.

The code which I have written in scss file

```
.icon-addMember {
  display: flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-image: url("src/app/assets/images/image/addmember.svg") no-repeat 100% 100% !important;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

In typescript

```
 private generatePopupMenu(): void {
    this.addMemberPopup = [
      {
        label: '',
        items: [
          {
            label:this.addMemberLabel,
            icon: 'icon-addMember',
            style: { 'background-image': `url(${assetUrl('images/addmember.svg')}`, 'background-position': '10% 50%', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat' },
            command: () => {
              this.popUpTitle = this.addMemberLabel;
              this.templateName = this.addMemberContent;
            }
          },          
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
```

If i try to add icon-addmember in p-menuitem-icon its not working?

Please any help or suggestions would be very helpful...
Thanks in advance.